# C# Launch application with multiple arguments doesn't seem to work with textbox

Tags: c#

I can get all the arguments to this program to work when I set them in the code but when I use a textbox for the item ID it just doesn't work properly

```
            Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Plex\Plex Media Server\Plex Media Scanner.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = ("--analyze-deeply --force --item" + textBox1.Text + "--log-file-suffix \"Deep Analysis\" ");
        p.Start();
```

Comment: What exactly does not work?
Have you tried with the debugger (or log output) to find out, what the value of p.StartInfo.Arguments is?
Eventually, create an object for ProcessStartInfo, first and pass it to the process

Comment: Getting this error "Error: unrecognised option '--item99--log-file-suffix'."
It should output something like this when I didn't use the textbox
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Plex\Plex Media Server\Plex Media Scanner.exe" --analyze-deeply --force --item 99 --log-file-suffix " Deep Analysis"

Comment: you are missing a space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Plex\Plex Media Server\Plex Media Scanner.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "--analyze-deeply --force --item " + textBox1.Text + " --log-file-suffix \"Deep Analysis\" ";
    p.Start();
```

You were just missing spaces before and after the textbox text.
Add them like in the answer and you will be fine